# SSH to Ubuntu Server VirtualBox from off network computer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

I'm working on setting up a webserver for development on an app I am developing and I need to be able to access the server from a computer on a different network than that which the server is being hosted on.  Is there any way to set this up so I can use an SSH client like putty to access my server when I am off of my home network?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a port forwarding option in the virtual box network interfaces configuration. I believe you want port 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Ubuntu server you need to install `openssh-sever`

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Port 22 is for `ssh` so you need to have this port enabled/forwarded through the Virtial Box network configuration.

Also you will probably need to check configuration of you SSH server in:

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

it has port it works with `Port 22`

you may like to enable Password Authentication. Uncomment then.

`#PasswordAuthentication yes`